how to route pods in kubernetes without using service?
Kind cluster node: c9s-control-plane.
jenkins pod ip: 10.244.0.6.
dind pod ip: 10.244.0.9.
containerlab ip deployed within dind pod: 172.20.20.0/24.
c9s-control-plane: 10.244.0.1 (pod gateway), 172.19.0.0/16(eth0).
The issue is jenkins can ping to dind but cannot ping to the containerlab even after the routing. Any solutions?
Routing on jenkins:
default via 10.244.0.1 dev eth0
10.244.0.0/24 via 10.244.0.1 dev eth0 src 10.244.0.6
10.244.0.1 dev eth0 scope link src 10.244.0.6
172.20.20.0/24 via 10.244.0.1 dev eth0

Routing on dind:
dink-7f64f88747-nhgnt:/# ip route
default via 10.244.0.1 dev eth0
10.244.0.0/24 via 10.244.0.1 dev eth0 src 10.244.0.9
10.244.0.1 dev eth0 scope link src 10.244.0.9
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.20.20.0/24 dev br-44150f9313a2 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.20.1

Routing on c9s-control-plane:
default via 172.19.0.1 dev eth0
10.244.0.2 dev vethd5a5bf09 scope host
10.244.0.3 dev vethb5b4f2c3 scope host
10.244.0.4 dev vethf4d2d278 scope host
10.244.0.6 dev veth69ac8af4 scope host
10.244.0.7 dev vethddc7804d scope host
10.244.0.9 dev veth107ab5da scope host
10.244.0.10 dev vethe2ad53b8 scope host
blackhole 10.244.107.128/26 proto bird
172.19.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.2
172.20.20.0/24 via 10.244.0.1 dev vethd5a5bf09

Update:
I have added network policy into my topology for dind which allows me to ping the gateway of containerlabs from jenkins. Now i can ping 172.20.20.1 but not 172.20.20.2 or 3.
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-jenkins-to-containerlab
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dink  # Modify if you need to target specific pods
  ingress:
    - from:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: jenkins  # Match the Jenkins pod label
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 2375  # The port Docker API listens on
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 8888  # The port VNC client connects on
  egress:
    - to:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: dink  # Allow egress to Dink pods


You can use the IP-per-Pod method because each pod has its own IP address, which other pods can use to reach it. also, you can use network plugins to assign unique ips to pod ie:- flannel.

Hi @ANISHKUMARMOURYA, thanks for answering. The pods itself can already communicate with each other. It is just jenkins cannot reach the container running in the dind pod even after routing. Not sure if setting a ip for each pods makes any difference.
